# Non-trivial Dozer mappings

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

I'm struggling to get [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) to bend to my will for something that I feel should be quite simple. I have two similar models that I wish to map between, however one has a 'deeper' hierarchy than the other and this is causing me problems when dealing with collections. Consider the following classes:

Source classes:

```
class Foo {
    String id;
    NameGroup nameGroup; 
    // Setters/Getters
}

class NameGroup {
    private List<Name> names;
    // Setters/Getters
}

class Name {
    private String nameValue;
    // Setters/Getters
}
```

Destination classes:

```
class Bar {
    private String barId;
    private BarNames barNames;
    // Setters/Getters
}

class BarNames {
    private List<String> names;
    // Setters/Getters
}
```

Now I'd like the following one-way mappings:

```
Foo.id -> Bar.barId // Simple enough
```

But I then need:

```
Foo.nameGroup.names.nameValue -> Bar.barNames.names
```

So each `Name` instance in `Foo.nameGroup.names` should result in a `String` being added to the `BarNames.names` list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be done with Dozer as long as your "Name" class contains a String constructor.

A quote from the Dozer docs (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html):

> Data type coversion is performed
>   automatically by the Dozer mapping
>   engine. Currently, Dozer supports the
>   following types of conversions: (these
>   are all bi-directional)
>
> ...
>
> String to
>   Complex Type if the Complex Type
>   contains a String constructor
>
> ...

I have tested this with your classes as above (I was stuck with the same problem) and it works perfectly.  Here is the mapping I used:

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>com.test.bar.Bar</class-a>
  <class-b>com.test.foo.Foo</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>barId</a>
    <b>id</b>
  </field>
  <field>
    <a>barNames.names</a>
    <b>nameGroup.names</b>
    <a-deep-index-hint>java.lang.String</a-deep-index-hint>
    <b-deep-index-hint>com.test.foo.Name</b-deep-index-hint>
  </field>
</mapping>
```